# Can we run Metro Web services on IIS?

Tags: web-services, iis, java-metro-framework

Can we run the web services created using METRO web service stack on the IIS server as opposed to Glassfish or tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not really make sense. Metro web services are Java based, they have nothing to do with IIS, therefore you can't run them on IIS. However you can implement the same logic in WCF and host it on IIS. You can also call Metro web services from WCF.